# Having difficulty with Logstash importing from sql server when trying to enable search suggestions field in elastic

Tags: json, ubuntu, elasticsearch, logstash, elk

Using a sql server table as my base with Columns Id (nvarchar), Title(nvarchar), Teacher(nvarchar), Websitecategory(nvarchar); i intend to leverage the elasticsearch mapping with a field named suggest for means of search suggestions capability specifically for Columns Title and Teacher.
I identified the place of Error causation is the script and scipt_params json object in output section of my Logstash .conf file and syntax may be incorrect, but have no idea how to fix it! appreciate every hint and help.
I encountered some phenomena like Logstash ingest every Row multiple time results in more documents than expected f.r : 1000 Rows throw back 365000 documents ! is that normal?
I assured all the routing are available such as template.json and certificate path , etc.
cpu_arch:X86_64 ,OS: ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS jellyfish CN, ELK_ver installed on my local machine: 8.10.2

Below is the Logstash_Configuration File :

```
input {
 jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/home/erfan/SearchHerkunft/logstash-8.10.2/lib/mssql-jdbc-12.4.1.jre11.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=WebScrapingProject_DB;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;trustStore=/home/erfan/SearchHerkunft/logstash-8.10.2/config/http_ca.crt"
    jdbc_user => "sa"
    jdbc_password => "Warner123#"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    jdbc_fetch_size => 10
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    statement => "SELECT TOP (1000) [Id]
      ,[Title]
      ,[Teacher]
      ,[WebSiteCategory]
 FROM [WebScrapingProject_DB].[dbo].[Test]"
 }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    copy => { "Id" => "[@metadata][_id]" }
    remove_field => ["Id", "@version"]
  }
  mutate {
    convert => { "[@metadata][_id]" => "string" }
  }
  mutate {
    add_field => { "suggest_input" => "%{[@metadata][Title]}" }
    add_field => { "suggest_input" => "%{[@metadata][Teacher]}" }
    add_field => { "suggest_weight" => 10 }
  }
}

output {
 elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://localhost:9200"]
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate_verification => true
    cacert => '/home/erfan/SearchHerkunft/logstash-8.10.2/config/http_ca.crt'
    user => "elastic"
    password => "AE1Qj2*vb73VIkpp4Nyh"
    index => "yabland"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
    document_type => "_doc"
    routing => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
    template => '/home/erfan/SearchHerkunft/logstash-8.10.2/config/template.json'
 }
}
```

And the mentioned template.json mentioned in the output section:

```
{
  "index_patterns": ["yabland-*"],
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": { "type": "keyword" },
      "title": { "type": "text" },
      "teacher": { "type": "text" },
      "webSiteCategory": { "type": "text" },
      "suggest": { "type": "completion", "analyzer": "simple" }
    }
  }
}
```

Further you wil see terminal command for executing Logstash, referencing the .conf file,as such :

```
erfan@erfan-SVF14218SAW:~/SearchHerkunft/logstash-8.10.2$ bin/logstash -f ~/SearchHerkunft/logstash-8.10.2/config/sqlJDBC.conf
```

expected to run and begin pipeline into the elasticsearch service

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.

The first problem is that in your mapping, `suggest` is all lowercase

```
  "suggest": { "type": "completion", "analyzer": "simple" }
   ^
   |
```

and in your script the field has an initial uppercase

```
ctx._source.Suggest
            ^
            |
       change this
```

Second, the error you're getting is because there is no `script_params` settings in the elasticsearch output. You need to access to the [event fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-script) using the `params.event.get('field')` syntax. So your script needs to look like this instead:

```
script => "ctx._source.suggest = [ 'input': [params.event.get('title'), params.event.get('teacher')], 'weight': 10]"
```

Moreover, I'm not sure why you're using `action => update` and `doc_as_upsert`... Why not simply indexing each record without resorting to scripting? I would simply build the suggest field in the filter section.

Comment: Mister Val, additional thanks for your recom on how to use suggest field; unfortunately it posts same error on the same line ['script'] after making changes you proposed! thus i decided to implement suggest in filter section as you mentioned, i'd be grateful you review and revise any flaws. i'll update the changes. However i didn't mean to build additional field for weight but the consequent filter will do this !